# Realm Android - createOrUpdateAllFromJson, obtain objects not contained

Tags: android, json, realm

Using createOrUpdateAllFromJson from [Realm Android Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#json) I read:

> Parsing JSON with Realm is subject to the following rules.
>
> 1. Creating object with JSON which has the field with a null value:
>
>    - For a not-required field, set it to null which is the default value.
>    - For a required field, throw an exception.
> 2. Updating object with JSON which has the field with a null value:
>
>    - For a not-required field, set it to null.
>    - For a required field, throw an exception.
> 3. JSON doesn’t have the field:
>
>    - Leave the value unchanged for both required and not-required fields.

Is there a way to obtain list of objects not contained in json (through the Primary Key)?

Comment: No, that isn't possible, at least not without doing it manually. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I need to update Realm Database with "createOrUpdateAllFromJson" without lost reference to other objects but removing object that not exist anymore in Json.

When I use "createOrUpdateAllFromJson" all works fine in create or update objects with PrimaryKey. Such documentation says this method not recognize a missing PrimaryKey but I need to delete RealmObject that no longer exist in that Json.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior ideas on how to achieve this in smart way (I don't know all Realm methods)?

Comment: @geolyth Maybe you can build a list of the primary keys from the JSON objects, query for object not on that list, and delete those?

Comment: @geisshirt In the end, I use createOrUpdateAllFromJson with some api modifications ;)